# react-navigation composing multiple navigations

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-drawer

Imagine I have three states in my application:

1. Home
2. Settings
3. Messages

I want to show first two link to these states in the bottom of screen, I can achieve that with this code:

```
const routeConfig = {
    Profile: {
        screen: Profile
    },
    Setting: {
        screen: Setting
    }
};
```

and I export it as my root component with this:

```
const TabBottomNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(routeConfig);
```

Now I want to show the third link, Messages in a drawer navigation, I see people do the with the following code:

```
const drawerRouteConfigs = {
    Home: {
        screen: TabNavigator,
    },
    Messages: {
        screen: Messages,
    }   
};

const drawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(drawerRouteConfig);
```

and the drawer navigator by this code:

```
const stackRouteConfigs = {
    DrawerNavigator: {
        screen: DrawerNavigator
    }
};

const stackNavigatorCofig = {
    initialRouteName: 'DrawerNavigator',
    headerMode: 'none'
};

const StackNavigator = createStackNavigator(stackRouteConfigs, stackNavigatorCofig);
```

My question is that should I always include tab navigation and drawer navigation as a screen in the main stack navigator?

and the same question for drawer navigator, Should I include my tab navigator in my drawer navigator?

my refrence link is this:

https://github.com/quangvietntd/AppBanHangReactNative/blob/master/App.js

Answer (score 0):

No, you need to include only tab navigation as a screen into the main Stack Navigator and into DrawerNavigator, include StackNavigator as a screen.

```
const AppWithSlideMenu = DrawerNavigator(
    {
        App: { screen: MainStackNavigator }
    },
    {
        contentComponent: Scenes.SlideMenuScene,
        drawerWidth: Dimensions.get('window').width * 0.88
    }
);

const MainStackNavigator = StackNavigator(
    {
    TabBar: { screen: TabBar },
    }
);
```

Comment: Why is that so? Which navigator should I expose to my `registerComponent` ?

Comment: AppWithSlideMenu.Like this:-<AppWithSlideMenu screenProps={this.props}  />